# Classical Electromagnetism: Constructive or destructive interference?

Tags: electromagnetism

Please consider this scenario: Laser light is split into two beams, one of which is sent on a path that takes it through a slab of glass, where light's speed is about two-thirds of what it is in air. The other beam travels an identical-length path, entirely in air. When the beams recombine, will the interference be constructive or destructive or somewhere in between? Or does it depend on the thickness of the glass? I think it has to depend on the thickness of the glass, because that's what will determine the phase of the waves. But I have seen an answer which says (without explanation) that the interference must be constructive. Any thoughts greatly appreciated.

Comment: It's both. The total energy in the beam doesn't change, hence there always have to be volumes with constructive and destructive interference. What is non-trivial about the Gedankenexperiment is the approximation that beams are perfectly plane waves and that we can therefor find an optical plane in which the two beams are interfering destructively without there being any release of energy. That is not what we would find in an experiment. Instead there will always be interference fringes, no matter how we choose the geometry.

Comment: @FlatterMann : "The total energy in the beam doesn't change" - I am not sure about that. Let us consider two sources of radiation located close to each other. Let us assume that the power of radiation from each of the sources working alone is $P$. Then the power radiated by the two sources working together can be different from $2P$ and will depend on the phase difference.

Comment: @akhmeteli That's correct for any one point. Integrated over the entire spatial volume the energy has to be the same due to energy conservation. I know it's counterintuitive.

Comment: @Flattermann I think this is what akhmeteli is saying, and I think he is right in this. Take two  antennas that are by themselves perfectly matched and place so close, say a wavelength apart, that they are now reactively coupled and thereby both are mismatched. As a result the sum of their total integrated over whole space output powers is not $P_1+P_2$ because neither radiates as much out as it would by itself alone.

Comment: @akhmeteli This is in fact the biggest headache of all phased array designers that the individual radiators can behave very differently as one varies the relative phases between them, there could even be essentially blind directions into/from which no radiation goes, etc.

Comment: @hyportnex I am talking about the total energy in all of the field. Of course one can design high Q resonant systems that do all kinds of things, including raising the power in the field by factors of thousands. Laser resonators are an example of that. No matter what we do, though, the energy has to go somewhere. I understood the question as "Can we interfere a beam "away"?". The answer is no, we can't. Interference does nothing to the total energy.

Comment: @FlatterMann : In my scenario, the energy is conserved, but the power radiated by one source depends on the field created by the other source, so the total radiated power from the two sources can depend on the phase difference between the sources. I know it's counterintuitive. https://pubs.aip.org/aapt/pte/article-abstract/52/7/428/277273/Interference-and-the-Law-of-Energy-Conservation?redirectedFrom=fulltext

Comment: @akhmeteli The beam pattern of two sources is not the same as the beam pattern of one source, so you are basically down to what I said, already. There is a secondary effect that coupled resonant antennas may or may not emit more total power, but that depends strongly on what is driving those antennas. In a laser emissions are stimulated and the material acts as a coherent amplifier, but none of that has anything to do with the free fields or the original question as far as I can tell.

Comment: @FlatterMann : Thank you for agreeing "that coupled resonant antennas may or may not emit more total power". Please see https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RRi4dv9KgCg , where  they use just one laser source in an interferometer, but the total energy radiated by the laser depends on the phase difference between the arms of the interferometer. This is relevant to the OP, but it is even more relevant to your phrase "The total energy in the beam doesn't change".

Comment: this is an instructive video from MIT on the complexity of laser light https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=J4Ecq7hIzYU

Comment: @akhmeteli Nothing in the original question indicates to me that the laser is meant to be anything other than a coherent source. The question starts with the words "classical electromagnetism". The amplification in a laser is a quantum effect.

Comment: @FlatterMann : I don't understand how your last comment is relevant. The total power radiated by a laser of an interferometer depends on the phase difference in the arms of the interferometer. This is relevant to the OP and to your phrase "The total energy in the beam doesn't change", which phrase is, strictly speaking, incorrect.

Comment: @akhmeteli The power of the laser (without feedback effects) is always the same. At most there will be reflection back into the laser itself, which is a poorly designed interferometer, if I may say so. One should never allow that to happen. Instead the beam should be dumped into an absorber. The word "interferometer" is nowhere being used in the original post. This will be my last reply to you.

Comment: @FlatterMann : " The power of the laser (without feedback effects) is always the same." However, in general, there is feedback, so your initial phrase remains incorrect. "The word "interferometer" is nowhere being used in the original post." The word is not used, but the following phrase from the OP clearly describes the main parts of an interferometer: "Laser light is split into two beams, one of which is sent on a path that takes it through a slab of glass... The other beam travels an identical-length path, entirely in air. When the beams recombine..."

Comment: @FlatterMann a 10GHz airborne phased array is as coherent a source as the concept "coherence" can be given meaning to. Still what comes *out* of each radiator depends on its neighbors, also there are "funny" other joint effects such as surface waves, etc. All in all, the individual radiators in an array have a lot more  complicated behavior than is indicated in introductory texts by quoting a finite Fourier transform, and is a complicated behavior that is a fine source of many well-paid *mortgages*. Energy is conserved but not in the form of spatial EM energy but rather as hotter amplifiers.

Comment: and, of course, a DEW laser can be an electrically steerable phased array of individual smaller laser sources with all the attendant problem of its 10GHz brothers/sisters...